# Serve a txt file programmatically with gae python

Tags: python, file, google-app-engine

I know that I can't write files into the google app engine system, but I wonder if from the  datastore I could programmatically build a txt file and serve it directly to download to the user of the application. I am not storing the file. I just want to serve it.

Any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. 
You need to set the header to indicate that the file must be an attachment.

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler): 
    def test_download(self):
        self.response.headers.add_header('content-disposition','attachment',filename='text.txt')                 

        self.response.write("hello world")
```

You can see more information looking at the [source for webapp2](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/_modules/webapp2.html)

Regarding "can't write files into the google app engine system", you can write to the blobstore instead. So if you need to generate a large file, you write it to the blobstore and serve it from there.